# Regex word break not working in newer version of bash

Tags: bash

I have a very simple example of searching for a whole word in bash:

```
TEST="red green blue"
if [[ $TEST =~ red\b ]]; then echo "true"; fi
```

This works fine in bash --version:

```
3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

But a newer server does not return true.

The bash version of the newer server is:

```
4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

If I remove the \b it returns true.

But in my case I need the \b to search for wordbreak, as I do not want it to return if a word is redden for example. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of shebang are you using in the script ?

Comment: Those commands are run from the command line, my scripts have #!/bin/sh